# Acceder dd/MM/yyyy - MaskFormatter en JFormattedTextfield

Tags: java, date, java-swing

Tengo un `JFormattedTextField` con patrón `dd-MM-yyyy` (18-05-2021).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo controlar si el "dd" está entre 01 y 31, o el año tiene una longitud de 4 dígitos y está entre 1900 o 2020? ¿Cómo puedo acceder a las 3 variables (`dd, mm, yyyy)` en el `JFormatTextField`?** Imaginaros que inserto el día y el mes, quedado el campo del año vacío, quisiera mostrar un mensaje por pantalla de que falta el año, por eso quiero poder acceder al `dd-MM-yyyy`

**Código:**

```
public class CalcularEdadVisual extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public CalcularEdadVisual() throws ParseException {
        initComponents();
        //Dar formato al JFormattedTextField yy-MM-dddd
        formattedtextfield.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new MaskFormatter("##/##/####")));
        
        //Forma de recuperar la fecha del sistema y darle un formato.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar fechaAhora = Calendar.getInstance();
        String fch = sdf.format(fechaAhora.getTime());
        label_fecha_hoy.setText("Hoy es: "+fch);
        
        //Datos del día de hoy.
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        final JFormattedTextField tf2 = new JFormattedTextField(dtf);
        tf2.setValue(new Date());
        System.out.println("Día: " +tf2.getValue());
        label_fecha_texto.setText(tf2.getText());
    }
        
    
    private void button_edadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        //JAVA 8.
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate fechaNac = LocalDate.parse(formattedtextfield.getText(), fmt);
        LocalDate ahora = LocalDate.now();

        Period periodo = Period.between(fechaNac, ahora);
        //System.out.print("Tu edad es: "+periodo.getYears()+"\n");
        label_calculo_edad.setText("Tienes "+String.valueOf(periodo.getYears())+" años.");
    }                                           


    private void formattedtextfieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                            
        char numero = evt.getKeyChar();
        if(!(numero >= '0' && numero <= '9')){
            evt.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

**Funcionalidad del programa**: Insertamos `dd-MM-yyy`, pulsamos `button`, y calculamos la edad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JFormattedTextField` implementa un *Verificador de Entrada* que no permite perder el foco con una entrada inválida.
Bien podrías aprovechar el mismo formateador tanto para la máscara como para la fecha:

```
public class FechaField extends JFormattedTextField{
   
   public FechaField( SimpleDateFormat f ){
      super( f );
      this.setInputVerifier( new FechaField.InputVerifier(f) );
   }
   
   public static class InputVerifier extends javax.swing.InputVerifier{
      
      private SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
      private GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
         
      public InputVerifier(SimpleDateFormat dateFormat){
         this.sdf = dateFormat;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean verify( JComponent input ){
         JFormattedTextField tf = (JFormattedTextField) input;
         System.out.println("Verificando "+tf.getText()+" para "+this.sdf.toPattern());
         try{
            Date d = this.sdf.parse(tf.getText());            
            this.gc.setTime(d);
            int dia = this.gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int año = this.gc.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
            
            System.out.println("Día: "+dia+" Año: "+año);
            if( año<1900 || año>2020 ){
               System.out.println("¡Año inválido!");
               // Aquí para avisarle al usuario, lo apropiado sería disparar un evento
               return false; // Con false no dejará perder el foco
            }
            
            return true;
         } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Excepción: "+e.getMessage());
         }
         return false;
      }
      
   }

}
```

La clase propuesta es una especialización de un campo de texto con formato sólo para fechas, con un verificador -de fechas- en particular.

En el método `verify()` obtenemos el formateador que se le pasó al constructor, observando que `JFormattedTextField` usa internamente `AbstractFormatter` en lugar de un descendiente de `java.text.Format`; es por eso que interceptamos en el constructor el `SimpleDateFormat` antes que termine enterrado en un `AbstractFormatter`.
Una vez parseada la fecha y con ayuda de un `GregorianCalendar` puedes obtener los componentes de la fecha y así aplicar las reglas de negocio que necesites.

En tu código simplemente harías:

```
        //Datos del día de hoy.
        final JFormattedTextField tf2 = new FechaField(sdf);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el ejemplo y sobretodo por la explicación. Clara y concisa. +1.